# Inject bean result into POJO object

Tags: java, apache-camel, pojo

imagine we have a POJO class like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyPojo
{    
    private Map<String, Object> myMap;
    private List<AnOtherPojoClass> myOtherPojos;
    private int myInteger;
}
```

This Type is used in a camel route triggered by REST DSL:

```
<post uri="/runpojo" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json" bindingMode="json" type="com.test.MyPojo">
            <route>
                <!-- pojo's myInteger is already filled from REST caller -->
                <setBody>
                    <simple>${body.setMyMap(${bean:service2?method=calculateMap(${body.myInteger})})}</simple>
                </setBody>
                <setBody>
                    <simple>${body.setMyOtherPojos(${bean:service3?method=calculateOtherPojo})}</simple>
                </setBody>
                <marshal ref="json" />
            </route>
        </post>
```

But here is my problem:
After invoking my POST I want to set a POJO property in my body. But `<simple/>` does not work, since it tries to convert `calculateMap(${body.myInteger})})` the method parameter to an String. As long as the parameter is a simple type this maybe works, but into my production code `myInteger` is an `byte[]`. Another problem is, even if I manage to get the bean running, the return value `Map<String, Object>` is (camel internal) parsed to a `String`, but my setter expect a `Map`.

Current version :

```
<camel.version>2.17.1</camel.version>
```

What can I do, to set POJO properties to an result of another beans method call?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: @ClausIbsen current camel version is   `<camel.version>2.17.1</camel.version>`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure we fixed this in a newer version, so upgrade your Camel.

Comment: going to test it with newer version `2.19.3`

Comment: I've updated camel, and currently get this exception : `RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: setMyMap(${bean:service2?method=calculateMap(${body.myInteger})}) on null due to: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$InvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:228)
...
 at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpMessage.createBody(HttpMessage.java:74)
...
` It looks a bit like `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10425`